# Cygwin tee delays other cygwin apps

Tags: cygwin

I run my program through tee:

```
<prog.exe> | tee out.txt
```

prog.exe runs for a long time, and sometimes I pause it (in the console) with the pause/break key. From that point, wincyg1.dll seems to be blocking, and any app that I run (e.g. ls.exe from another console window) would hang and wait until I release the break from the console that runs the tee.

EDIT

Some more details. As console, I'm using conemu (at the moment, I can't test cmd.exe.)

My app is a python extension (.pyd that was built with swig and visual studio and has nothing to do with cygwin), and I use it in a PyQt script.

I can't come up with a simple minimal example to reproduce the issue, and it would take some effort to track it down.

I guess right now I'm wondering if anyone is familiar with cygwin's architecture to answer if they use a mutex that would cause such a thing.

I merely use cygwin commands (e.g. ls, tee, grep, which) as convenient shell extensions, and they have nothing to do with my program.

Comment: I can not replicate. This is not a programming question anyway, but for debugging your problem you need to provide more info: which terminal; is `prog.exe` a cygwin program ?

Comment: I added some details.

Comment: try from Cygwin Terminal instead of ConEmu. It can be a side of https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2020-01/msg00003.html

Comment: If I run a clean cmd.exe (without conemu), and within it I run bash.exe (which otherwise would hang), then within it everything works fine (e.g. ls). Not sure how it's related to the issue in your link, but it seems like conemu has issues with cygwin in general.

Comment: only last 3.1.x versions as a new feature was introduced that ConEmu is not able to manage. Next cygwin Release should have a workaround for it